# CMD Batch File With Muliple Inputs

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to automate a command that prompts the users for their pin, the command in question;

```
tpmvscmgr.exe create /name "vSmartcard" /pin prompt /adminkey default generate
```

at this point you press enter, the next thing you see is

```
Enter Pin:
```

You enter the pin and press enter, then you get asked to confirm the pin before pressing enter again.

How can I automate this in a batch file, or in powershell? I haven't been able to find any commands that work in a similar way to even get a start on it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to automate? Are you trying simply to skip the confirmation of the pin, the piece of info the program deems important enough to ask you to enter twice? Or are you trying to omit the typing-in part altogether, having got a list of pins in a text file?

Comment: Also, the program's `/pin` switch seems to require an argument after it, and you put `prompt` there. Is it the only option? Would it accept something like a `/pin 1234`, where `1234` stands for a pin, previously typed in, then supplied as a parameter?

Comment: So say I've built a fresh machine I want to create the virtual smartcard and set the pin. I want it to run from a script to save a user having to go in and do it. It won't accept /pin 1234 (we've filed it as a bug) so I just want to automate running the command and the input of a pin

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the trick below work with your particular program; but even in this case, if the program prompts for an additional input it must be placed inside the parenheses next to the pin number. Perhaps this is enough for your needs...

```
@echo off
(
echo pinnum
echo pinnum
) | tpmvscmgr.exe create /name "vSmartcard" /pin prompt /adminkey default generate
```

Comment: Close but it attempts to put the pin in before running the tpmvscmgr.exe

Comment: @AliBeasley: Excuse me, I think I don't understand your comment. What exactly happens? The program freeze waiting for the pin? The given pinnum is ignored? Else? ...

Comment: So running that command, the pin is entered before the program asks for it, so it just sits there waiting for the user to enter the pin.

Comment: @AliBeasley: The "it just sits there waiting for the user to enter the pin" part indicate that this trick does not work with your program (as long as the program still read the pin from keyboard). However, your "the pin is entered before the program asks for it" comment have no sense... What do you mean with that?

Comment: Aacini: Perhaps that was just a surmise based on the fact that the program didn't accept the input from the `echo`s. @AliBeasley: Most probably, the lines were passed to `tpmvscmgr.exe`'s stdin (and in good time too), but the program might have ignored them. Maybe it was because the program used a different way of reading the user input than through stdin. That is not uncommon: some programs that request user name and password would also behave like that, thus preventing you from automating authentication process *this* way. So, to summarise, this *could* work in some cases, just not in yours.